# Plotting an ETF price for longer time period

Tags: python

I have the code below.  If you run my code the graph will be showing price history for just one year. Can someone tell me how I can plot SPY instrument for the whole time period from 01.01.2008 until now.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt from pandas_datareader import data as web
from pylab import plt plt.style.use('ggplot') 
%matplotlib inline 

spy=web.DataReader("SPY",data_source="google",start="2008-1-1") 
spy["Close"].plot()
```

Comment: Very hard to understand the structure of your data

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguous question but I am kind of newbie. Data is in table format with dates on the first column then follow five columns labeled "Open", "High", "Low", "Close" and "Volume". If you put 
     spy.tail() before last line of code and then run the code
you will get idea of how the data is structured

Comment: We were all there some day